# How do I write an Microsoft Access SQL Query in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to run this Microsoft Access query in C#, but it isn't working:

```
Create table Users (UserName Text(50) Primary Key, Password Text(50), IsLocked YESNO)
```

I get a `Syntax error in field definition` error.

How do I write a Microsoft Access SQL Query in C#?

Comment: Does adding [xx] around the table and column names help? ie. `Create table [Users] ([UserName] ...`

Comment: Also, try replacing the YESNO type with Text(1) and see if it works then, I seem to remember that DAO has problems with some types due to lack of updates. Seem to remember this was with the Decimal type, but perhaps YESNO has the same fate. In other words, try experimenting and removing each column to see which one is the problem.

Comment: Thanks Lasse. Adding [xx] solved my problem.

Comment: @Lasse: You need to add that as an answer. It's a good answer; I'd vote for it.  Comments aren't meant to be answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Create Table [Users] ([UserName] Text(50) Primary Key, [Password] Text(50), [IsLocked] YESNO)
```